# Strange Type Initialization Exception

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, typeinitializationexception

I am using the following code:

```cs
var client = new HttpClient();
var result = await client.GetAsync("http://example.com/");
var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine(response);
```

on Visual Studio 2019 version 16.9.4  and the project is in .NET 5 
Everything is OK when I use :

1. CTRL+F5 (Release or Debug)
2. Step by step mode - <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> on Debug

But when i use <kbd>F5</kbd> that strange error  (TypeInitializationException) occurs:

```
The type initializer for 'Microsoft.IntelliTrace.TelemetryObserver.IntelliTraceObserver' threw an exception.
   at Microsoft.IntelliTrace.TelemetryObserver.IntelliTraceObserver.IsEnabled(String telemetryName)
   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticListener.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Subscribe>b__0(String name, Object arg1, Object arg2)
   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticListener.IsEnabled(String name, Object arg1, Object arg2)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.<SendAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsyncCore>d__85.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at MyAwesomeApp.Program.<Main>d__0.MoveNext() in X:\MyAwesomeApp\Program.cs:line 13
```

on Program.cs line 13 there exists first await statement(see code above)
And the inner exception is: (FileNotFoundException)

```cs
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IntelliTrace.TelemetryObserver.Common, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

   at Microsoft.IntelliTrace.TelemetryObserver.IntelliTraceObserver..cctor()
```

the same thing happens when using .net .netcore .net standard and with other project types.
and this prevents me normal debugging so as a lazy-fix I find TelemetryObserver.Common's dll file and add it as a reference to every project I want to debug normally but I know this is not a true solution
Another thing is that this exception occurs only when code does network calls or database connections or smth like that
I am aware when the TypeInitializationException may occur and its use cases.
Since it is not my code I dont know the cause so I think this is smth like configuration on Visual Studio to load that dll file on debugging and I dont know how to avoid it 
That is where I need help.

Comment: Have you tried disabling intellitrace? Tools -> Options -> IntelliTrace

Comment: OK, great @canton7 ,I tried that , It Occurs when Intellitrace enabled and one of "IntelliTrace events only(managed only)" , "IntelliTrace snapshots(managed and native)" is selected,  Does that mean intellitrace modules are corrupted ?

Comment: I've no idea why it's not loading Microsoft.IntelliTrace.TelemetryObserver.Common when it needs to. Best thing would be to click the little speech bubble under the "X" button in the top right then "Report a problem". That lets the VS team collect any traces and logs from VS, and see what's going on

Comment: Sounds like either a VS bug, or something that could be fixed via a repair of your VS install.